# newpx package introduces blank/space after footnote

Tags: fonts, footnotes

The following code produces an error:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newpxtext}

\begin{document}
Text\footnote{foo}:
Next text\footnotemark.
\footnotetext{bar} <= there is a space here, before the colon. It shouldn't be there!
\end{document}
```

Including this in the preamble after the newpxtext package solves it.

```
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
```

This solves it too:

```
\usepackage[defaultsups]{newpxtext}
```

However, both solutions do not incorporate the `newpx` superscript fonts.

Does anybody know why this happens? I like the `newpx` packages, but the footnote superscripts get borked by it. Am I doing something wrong? Are there newer Palatino font packages that include the improved scaling, metrics, etc. the `newpx` packages have that the `pxfonts` package does not?

Comment: You should report this problem to the package author. He's very prompt in fixing bugs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In version 1.08 of `newpxtext` (`newpxtext.sty 2014/01/09 v1.08`) the issue has been removed.

Note that the bug has been corrected also in `newtxtext` (`newtxtext.sty    2014/01/09 v1.19`).

Answer (score 6):

There is a missing `%` in the package definition

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newpxtext}
\makeatletter
\ifzpl@defaultsups %
\else
  \def\f@@tn@te{footnote}
  \def\@makefnmark{%
    \ifx\@mpfn\f@@tn@te%
      \ifx\thefootnote\orig@footnote%
        \hbox{\sustyle\hspace*{.04em}\@thefnmark}%%%%%%%%%% missing
      \else%
        \orig@makefnmark
      \fi
    \else%
      \orig@makefnmark
    \fi}
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Text\footnote{foo}:
Next text\footnotemark.
\footnotetext{bar} <= there is a space here, before the colon. It shouldn't be there!
\end{document}
```

Or update your distribution, then you'll get a fixed `newpxtext` and `newtxtext` package.

Comment: Beat me by one minute. ;-) There are several useless `%`, but not the important one.